# Two select fields dependent on each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

what I'm trying to do is to create two select fields and after selecting some option in the first one, some of options in the second should be hidden.
I'm almost there, except the fact, that my script can't find certain option out of the first select field, but when I put such option in the first it works, but only with the first one, so it's useless. I need it to hide options in the second select field according to option chosen in the first one.

What makes it all more difficult is the fact that I can't add any classes or ids or anything actually here.

I think I've made some mistake that consists of the way I tell the script which element should it edit, but I have no idea how to write it another way.

HTML

```
<select name="NameOne">
  <option value="First">Lorem Ipsum1</option>
  <option value="Second">Lorem Ipsum2</option>
  <option value="Third">Lorem Ipsum3</option>
  <option value="CD">Dolor2</option>
</select>

<select name="NameTwo">
  <option value="AB">Dolor1</option>
  <option value="CD">Dolor2</option>
  <option value="EF">Dolor3</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$("select").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "Second") {
    $('option[value="CD"]', this).addClass('hidden');
  } else {
    $('option[value="CD"]', this).removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

Please, help.

Comment: why can't you add classes or ids?

Comment: there are 2 wrong approaches in your code.1.$('option[value="CD"]', this) ==>IS THE WRONG APPROACH. Because by using that you can't separate options from select boxes. It will return options from both select box. Actually  only both all of the page content options <br/> 2.$("select") is also wrong==>because it select both select boxes not only firs one. But according to your requirement that is enough to consider Select box one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working because of this code here:

```
$('option[value="CD"]', this)...
```

In simple words, `this` checks for the option on select which is currently clicked. Since you clicked the first select, `this` becomes the first select and it tries to find option with values CD on it which is not present. So what you do?? Simple, get the second select, find option with values CD in it and change the class :)

Try this

```js
// you can change this to select first select only since selecting all the select doesnot make sense. 
$("select").change(function(){
//$("select[name='NameOne']").change(function(){ <--- better
  var secondSelect = $("select[name='NameTwo']"); //get second select
  if($(this).val() == "Second") {
    secondSelect.find('option[value="CD"]').addClass('hidden'); //find option with CD and add Class
  } else {
    secondSelect.find('option[value="CD"]').removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="NameOne">
  <option value="First">Lorem Ipsum1</option>
  <option value="Second">Lorem Ipsum2</option>
  <option value="Third">Lorem Ipsum3</option>
  <option value="CD">Dolor2</option>
</select>

<select name="NameTwo">
  <option value="AB">Dolor1</option>
  <option value="CD">Dolor2</option>
  <option value="EF">Dolor3</option>
</select>
```

```
$("select").change(function(){
 var secondSelect = $(select["name='NameTwo']"); 
 if($(this).val() == "Second") {
    secondSelect.find('option[value="CD"]').addClass('hidden');
  } else {
    secondSelect.find('option[value="CD"]').removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should query on a specific `select` and then hide the `option` in the other select, without `this` which would only do those `option`s in the `select` that changed.

```js
$("select[name='NameOne']").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "Second") {
    $("select[name='NameTwo'] option[value='CD']").addClass('hidden');
  } else {
    $("select[name='NameTwo'] option[value='CD']").removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="NameOne">
  <option value="First">Lorem Ipsum1</option>
  <option value="Second">Lorem Ipsum2</option>
  <option value="Third">Lorem Ipsum3</option>
  <option value="CD">Dolor2</option>
</select>

<select name="NameTwo">
  <option value="AB">Dolor1</option>
  <option value="CD">Dolor2</option>
  <option value="EF">Dolor3</option>
</select>
```